# Does account's reputation transfer over to Stack Overflow For Teams?

Tags: support, reputation, stack-overflow-for-teams

If I were to use Stack Overflow for teams, would user accounts in any way tie to main site accounts or do all users get fresh new accounts?

I understand that each post on Teams are private, but I'm wondering if the accounts are in any way tied to non-team accounts.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you're logged in to your SO account (which we recommend) then you have a single account similar to how it works with the network sites. Of course, you could always create a separate account.

As for rep, it is separate in your team vs SO public. You can see your rep in the top bar based on your context.

Comment: Maybe this should be in the help page for reputation on the Teams help center? (Also there's a typo there: _"Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the  trusts you;"_ I'm guessing "team" or "site" should be between "the" and "trusts")

Comment: @kendra I'll ping someone to update the help.

Comment: @JoeFriend is there any risk of accidental account merging? Suppose I wanted to keep my teams and main site separate (let's say I don't want my team members knowing my main site account).

Comment: @pault at the moment, account merges for Team members are disabled as a safety measure.  Longer term we'll be implementing _something_ to handle the cases where accounts are accidentally created (the most common cause of merges), but we aren't planning to merge without confirmation or anything like that that might leak Teams information (including membership).